# How do I create only ONE mandatory field in my data entry form for Google Sheet App Script button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, spreadsheet

I have created a data entry form on google sheets that has a submit button that triggers a script. I want to ensure that only one field is not left blank when someone submits the form through the script.

I want the script to check if the field (C5) is blank and return a SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert rejecting the submission as follows:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please enter mandatory field in C5.');
```

I have tried the below function's code that ensures that ALL fields are not blank when someone submits the form through the script however I only want one field (C5) to be mandatory not all of them. Can someone please help? :)

```js
function submitData() {
  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSS    = ss.getSheetByName("Form"); //Form Sheet
  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName("OrderInput"); 
   
  //Input Values
  var values = [[formSS.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C13").getValue()]];

  //Check Blank Values
  for (i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    if (values[0][i] == '') {
      var blankExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (blankExists) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please enter all mandatory fields.');
  }
  else {
    datasheet.getRange(datasheet.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 5).setValues(values);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Request successfully submitted!');
    formSS.getRange("C5").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C7").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C9").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C11").clear();
    formSS.getRange("C13").clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  //Check Blank Values
  /*
  for (i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    if (values[0][i] == '') {
      var blankExists = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  */
  var blankExists = values[0][0] == '';
```

Answer (score 0):

**The reason your code is not working as expected is mainly because you are checking the entire `values` array for the empty values.**

In order to fix this you will have to replace the `for` loop with a simple `if`:

```
if (values[0] == '')
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Please enter the required value in C5.');
```

Also, since you are using a one dimensional array, I suggest you change your `values` variable to this:

```
 var values = [formSS.getRange("C5").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C7").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C9").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C11").getValue(),
                 formSS.getRange("C13").getValue()];
```

Comment: Thank you! but what if I had to make both "C5" and "C11" mandatory? would that still work?

Comment: you would have to modify the `if` condition to: `if (values[0] == '' && values[3] == '')`

Comment: I tried what you suggested but now i'm receiving the below error......  Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Range.setValues.
submitDataNEW @ test.gs:17